# Simple stack corruption in C

Tags: c, stack, buffer-overflow

Can somebody explain me, why in this program if I call the `printf` in that way the flag will be win? but without will not? Why this `printf` allow such things i can't understand thanks. Why without the `printf` the array can't overwrite the variable flag?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {

    int flag = false;

    int arr[10] = {0};
    int siz = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(* arr);

    printf("%p", &flag);
    arr[10] = 1; // Without the printf call can't get the win. Why?
    puts("");

    if(flag == true)
    {
        printf("win !");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("lose");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` isn't what is broken in this code. `arr[10] = 1;` invokes *undefind behavior*. After that, stop trying to make sense out of this; there isn't any.

Comment: `arr[10]` is one past the end of the array. The array is declared `int arr[10]` so `arr[9]` is the last element. Thus, `arr[10] = 1;` is undefined behavior (i.e. crash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program acesses the array beyond it's bounds. The array indexes start at *0* and end at *N - 1* where *N* is the size of the array.

Doing this invokes undefined behavior, so your prediction of program's behavior will be wrong after this. Adding the `printf()` can change this behavior and it does, and that is what *undefined behavior* means, it should not affect the behavior of the program but once you have caused the undefined behavior at

```
arr[10] = 1;
```

you cannot know how the program will behave anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is causing your problem

```
arr[10] = 1;
```

You only allocate 10 elements in your array

```
int arr[10] = { 0 };
```

`arr[10]` is actually trying to access the 11th element in the array because array indices start at `0`.